# Storm-Crawler integration with Cassandra and build topology in Gradle

Tags: cassandra, apache-storm, stormcrawler

I tried to implement Storm-Crawler in my project but I need to work with Cassndra and Gradle. I have fun with Storm-Crawler and ElasticSearch stack but in this situatiom I'm forced to use this solutions. I tried a several times build uber jar with gradle but without success. Did anyone build Storm-Crawler topology in gradle? I configure Apache-Storm to use Cassandra but how put data from Strom-Crawler into Cassandra?

Answer (score 0):

Can't help with Gradle I am afraid but for the Cassandra part: do you want to store the content and metadata of the documents in it or use it for storing the info about the URLs too (as done with the status index in ES)? For the former, implement your own indexer extending [AbstractIndexerBolt](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/digitalpebble/stormcrawler/indexing/AbstractIndexerBolt.java), for the latter, you'll need a status updater and spout, which is a bit more complex.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply! Cassandra will be used to storing content from websites in order to search some useful information for my project.. Ok I will begin from implementing IndexerBolt.